# Updating a child from a child not working

Tags: delphi

Form 10 creates and shows form11 and form11 creates and shows form12.  Then form12 tries to update a control on form10 (successful), a control on form11(access violation) and control on form12(successful).  Why do I get an access violation updating the middle form, form11.  Commented Statements 30 and 31 do not work and I would like to know why please.  30 is updating the middle form.  31 is an aside, not related but it does not work and I am not sure why it bombs.

```
1: unit Unit10;
2:
3: interface
4:
5: uses
6: Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
7: Dialogs, StdCtrls;
8:
9: type
10: TForm10 = class(TForm)
11: Button1: TButton;
12: procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
13: private
14: { Private declarations }
15: public
16: { Public declarations }
17: end;
18:
19: var
20: Form10: TForm10;
21:
22: implementation
23: uses Unit11;
24:
25: {$R *.dfm}
26:
27: procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
28: var
29: fForm11 : TForm11;
30: begin
31: fForm11 := TForm11.Create(Application);
32: fForm11.show;
33: end;
34:
35: end. 

1: unit Unit11;
2:
3: interface
4:
5: uses
6: Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
7: Dialogs, StdCtrls;
8:
9: type
10: TForm11 = class(TForm)
11: Button1: TButton;
12: procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
13: private
14: { Private declarations }
15: public
16: { Public declarations }
17: end;
18:
19: var
20: Form11: TForm11;
21:
22: implementation
23: uses Unit12, Unit10;
24:
25: {$R *.dfm}
26:
27: procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
28: var
29: fForm12 : TForm12;
30: begin
31: form10.Button1.Caption := 'done';
32: fForm12 := TForm12.Create(Self);
33: fForm12.show;
34: end;
35:
36: end.

1: unit Unit12;
2:
3: interface
4:
5: uses
6: Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
7: Dialogs, StdCtrls;
8:
9: type
10: TForm12 = class(TForm)
11: Button1: TButton;
12: procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
13: private
14: { Private declarations }
15: public
16: { Public declarations }
17: end;
18:
19: var
20: Form12: TForm12;
21:
22: implementation
23: uses Unit11, Unit10;
24:
25: {$R *.dfm}
26:
27: procedure TForm12.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
28: begin
29: Form10.Button1.Caption := 'Unit10';
30: //Form11.Button1.Caption := 'Unit11';   //get an access violation
31: //Form12.Button1.Caption := 'Unit12';   //get an access violation           
32: Button1.Caption := 'Unit12';            //this same as 31 without Form12 prefix
33: end;
34:
35: end.
```

Comment: We are very happy for you to ask novice questions, but we expect you to read the answers and take heed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pay more attention to your variable names, declaration, and use.

You have two totally separate variables related to `Form11` in the code you've posted.

The first is the *global* `Form11` added automatically by the IDE (which should be deleted if you're not auto-creating your forms, because that's the only reason for its existence in the first place), declared in the `interface` section of `Unit11.pas`:

```
type
 TForm11 = class(TForm)
   Button1: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 private
 { Private declarations }
 public
 { Public declarations }
 end;

 var
    Form11: TForm11
```

The second is a *local* variable named `fForm11` which you declared in `Unit10.pas`, in your button click handler:

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fForm11 : TForm11;
begin
```

The second one is the one you're assigning the actual instance of the form you create:

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fForm11 : TForm11;
begin
  fForm11 := TForm11.Create(Application);   // Assigns to the *local* fForm11
  fForm11.show;                             // Shows this copy of the form
end;
```

The one you use in `Unit12`, where you've commented it out and mentioned that it causes an access violation is the *global* `Form11`, which is the only one that is visible in this code:

```
procedure TForm12.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form10.Button1.Caption := 'Unit10';
  //Form11.Button1.Caption := 'Unit11';   //get an access violation
  //Form12.Button1.Caption := 'Unit12';   //get an access violation           
  Button1.Caption := 'Unit12';            //this same as 31 without Form12 prefix
end;
```

The problem is that you've never created an instance of `TForm11` and assigned it to `Form11`; you created and assigned it to the *local* `fForm11` instead, which is not in scope at all.

The fix should be clear: Remove the local variable, and assign the form you create there to the proper variable.

The appropriate fix for you, however, would be to just auto-create the forms because you're using them willy-nilly all over the place very recklessly. With such bad use of inter-module dependencies, you're going to end up having the same types of problems over and over again, with things not being created when you're trying to access them.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, your instruction helped me solve my access violation issues.

Comment: @OwenH You can show your gratitude by accepting Ken's answer, clicking the check mark to the left of it.